# define parent with elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, parent-child

I am trying to put parent/child relationships into ElasticSearch. I was able to put my parents into ES but when I try to add the child objects I get the following error
`elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestsError: TransportError(400:, 'illegal_argument_exception', "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured")`

I understand, that I have to tell ES that my parents are actually parents somewhere in mappings. But where and how?
This is how I do it right now:

```
# the parent
es.index(index='www01', doc_type='domain', id=k, body=json.dumps(rest))
# the child
es.index(index='www01', doc_type='framework', id=key, body=json.dumps(value), parent=k)
```

**Edit:**
Alright. I think I've got it now. You really have to type everything that deviates from the standard settings explicitly into a mapping and create an empty index with that mapping first.
In this mapping you have to say that your child type has a parent with a specific type. (The ElasticSearch documentation is pretty clear) [RTFM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html)
After you've created your specific mapping on an empty index, you can put your stuff in.
Note: You don't have to specify everything in your mapping, just everything that is not "standard". So at first it is enough to just give the relationships. If you later want to say that some fields are dates or geo-coordinates you can later specify that. But keep in mind, that you have to empty your index first. **So save your data somewhere!**

Here is what I did:

```
def del_all_indices():
    print "----- deleting the following indices (not >>.kibana<<) -----"
    for idx in es.indices.get('*'):
        print idx
        if not idx == ".kibana":
            es.indices.delete(index=idx, ignore=[400, 404])
    print "----- remaining indices -----"
    for idx in es.indices.get('*'):
        print idx

create_index_body = {
    "mappings": {
        "domain": {},
        "framework": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "domain"
            }
        }
    }
}

del_all_indices()

es.indices.create(index='www01', body=create_index_body)

# the parent
es.index(index='www01', doc_type='domain', id=k, body=json.dumps(rest))
# the child
es.index(index='www01', doc_type='framework', id=key, body=json.dumps(value), parent=k)
```

It goes without saying, that if I'm missing something, please tell me. (I hope this helps, since there is almost no documentation on that topic.)